# Why does this bash script produce error?

Tags: bash

This simple script - to check whether a process is running and then send an email if it's not - works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f  "ghost.py" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running" > /dev/null
else
    echo "Looks like ghost.py stopped" | mail -s "ghost.py down" shaney.jones@gmail.com
fi
```

However, my attempt to have an OR operator in there to check two scripts fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ pgrep -f  "ghost.py" ] || [ pgrep -f "ghost2.py" ] > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running" > /dev/null
else
    echo "Looks like a script stopped" | mail -s "Script down" shaney.jones@gmail.com
fi
```

The error just says '-bash: [: -f: binary operator expected'

Comment: Drop the brackets. It's totally another command.

Comment: You don't want to evaluate the **output** of the command within `[ pgrep -f  "ghost.py" ]`, you simply want to evaluate the **Exit status** of the command  `pgrep -f  "ghost.py"`. Then you can simply use `||` (OR) as with any *compound command*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the brackets as it's completely another command (usually equivalent to `test`):

```
if pgrep -f  "ghost.py" || pgrep -f "ghost2.py" > /dev/null
then
  # Your stuff
```

See `help test` and `man test` for more details about the `[` command.